# XPATH - Get all nodes below a particular node

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following XML, I want to retrieve all the nodes below the node which contains, *in this example*, EEUU.

```
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:L>
         <ns1:A>33</ns1:A>
         <ns1:B>ok</ns1:B>
         <ns1:C>
            <ns1:D>EEUU</ns1:D>
            <ns1:E>1</ns1:E>
            <ns1:F>
               <ns1:G>
                  <ns1:G>20</ns1:G>
                  <ns1:H>NY</ns1:H>
               </ns1:G>
               <ns1:I>
                  <ns1:J>30</ns1:J>
                  <ns1:K>SFO</ns1:K>
               </ns1:I>
               <ns1:I>
                  <ns1:J>40</ns1:J>
                  <ns1:K>JFK</ns1:K>
               </ns1:I>
            </ns1:F>
         </ns1:C>
      </ns1:L>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So far, I've tried with the absolute path, but I can't get all the info below EEUU (20, NY, 30, SFO, 40, JFK).

Any advice?

Comment: Advice: don't forget the namespace.

Comment: Dear Alex, would you mind to give feedback if one of the proposed solutions solved your problem and if so accept one of the answers, please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This would do the work:

```
//ns1:D[text() = 'EEUU']/following::*/text()[normalize-space(.)]
```

**Edit on advice of @Uwe Block:**

```
//ns1:D[text() = 'EEUU']/following-sibling::*/descendant-or-self::*/text()[normalize-space(.)]
```

This version is more precise and better for a slightly changed xml. Now it gets *only* following siblings and their childs.

Answer (score 1):

I still do have difficulties to use XPATH namespaces properly. So, I found a solution which ignores namespaces (may be not the best idea but it works for me):

```
//*[local-name() = "D"][text() = "EEUU"]/following-sibling::*/descendant-or-self::*/text()[normalize-space(.)]
```

Except for `local-name()` this is very similar to the answer of @uL1. However, it does not take *all* following nodes but only the following siblings and all of their descendants.

I've tested it with [XPATH Tester/Evaluator - Online Toolz](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php) (after having fixed the malformed XML with help of [Simple online XPath tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath)) which returned the result

```
1
-----------------------
20
-----------------------
NY
-----------------------
30
-----------------------
SFO
-----------------------
40
-----------------------
JFK
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//ns1:C[ns1:D = 'EEUU']//*
```

will give you all elements inside the respective `<n1:C>`.

You will have to register the namespace prefix `ns1` and URI before this starts to work. Consult the documentation of your XML library or -tool to find out how. (Registering namespaces for XPath queries is an incredibly common operation, you will find tons of advice for every environment.)